# Qt Layout Flexible Grid

Tags: qt, layout

I have a bunch of buttons in Qt with a fixed size. Now I want to create a layout in which they are shown in a grid. I want the grid to be scrollable and when I resize my mainwindow, the grid should fit as much buttons in the layout as possible. The number of rows and columns are therefore not fixed.

I tried creating this with the hbox, vbox and gridlayout but they either put all the buttons below each other, or side by side. Also it resizes my mainwindow to an enormous size to fit all the buttons in.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put QScrollArea inside your QMainWindow. Apply QGridLayout to QScrollArea's inside widget and put the buttons inside it.

Comment: Hi Riateche, thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion but all the buttons are placed in one column, far less high than the buttons should be.. It seems the grid doesn't take up all the space it should

Comment: Try to set `setWidgetResizable(true)` for ``QScrollArea`.

Comment: Thanks, it sadly didn't change anything

Comment: To elaborate: The buttons are now in a Grid layout. The grid layout is assigned to a scrollarea. The scrollarea is part of a hboxlayout which is set to a frame. The frame is part of a qwidget which is set as the central widget of the mainwindow.

Comment: The grid layout should be assigned to scrollarea's internal widget, not to scrollarea itself. Central widget should have some layout too.